# Getting json file from url with Accept-Language headers

Tags: php, json, curl, header

The JSON link I am trying to download through this Curl handler is requesting headers with Accept-Language and Encoding.

I need to put it somewhere but i dont know where. Any suggestion?

[**This is my PHP CURL code helper.**](http://codepad.org/w1agoZzu)

Comment: You should post the relevant code here.

Comment: It tells me that my content is only mostly code and cannot post it.